# My .DLL compiles perfectly but crashes at runtime?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I'm assuming the file crashes because upon injection, I get a waiting cursor and the window never pops up. It compiles perfectly with no warnings or errors, and then does not work at run time. Any explanation as to why I am getting this would be of great help to me fixing it. Thanks!

Code (updated today):

```
#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK DllWindowProcedure(HWND ParentWindow, UINT Message, WPARAM WParam, LPARAM LParam)
{
    switch (Message)
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            //Do stuff.
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            ExitThread(0);
        break;
        case WM_QUIT:
            ExitThread(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(ParentWindow, Message, WParam, LParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

DWORD __stdcall Initiate(void * PData)
{
    WNDCLASSEX WindowClass;
    WindowClass.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    WindowClass.lpszClassName = "DllWindowClass";
    WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = DllWindowProcedure;
    WindowClass.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    WindowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    WindowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    WindowClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    WindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    WindowClass.lpszMenuName = "DllMenuClass";
    WindowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    WindowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    WindowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_BACKGROUND;
    HINSTANCE Instance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    HWND ParentWindow = CreateWindowEx(
        NULL,
        "DllWindowClass",
        "Agsploit - v1.1 - By: Agluk15",
        (WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX),
        200,
        200,
        500,
        400,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        Instance,
        NULL
    );
    ShowWindow(ParentWindow, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    MSG Messages;
    while (GetMessage(&Messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Messages);
        DispatchMessage(&Messages);
    };
    return NULL;
};

bool WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE DllInstance, DWORD Reason, LPVOID Reserved)
{
    DisableThreadLibraryCalls(DllInstance);
    if (Reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        CreateThread(0, 0, Initiate, 0, 0, 0);
    };
    return true;
};
```

Comment: Happens all the time. Compiling code does not mean the logic is good. Have you tested the DLL code without the DLL wrapper to be sure it works?

Comment: DLL wrapper? Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with your terminology. Maybe a bit of an explanation..?

Comment: Did you test the code before turning it into a DLL?

Comment: It was always a DLL. The code is from someone elses source so it should work fine..

Comment: *It compiles* only means you have no syntax errors. It does not mean your code is correct functionally. What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code? How are you *injecting* it? What are you *injecting* it into? Where's your test app you used during development to load the DLL?

Comment: DllMain is not the appropriate place to be adding feature code.  You should export `Initialize` from your DLL and explicitly invoke Initialize from your EXE.  (Either via GetProcAddress after LoadLibrary or just calling it directly because of direct linkage).

Comment: Off topic: Watch out for [ExitThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682659(v=vs.85).aspx). It's not a good friend to C++. When the thread goes away, it leaves without cleaning up, unrolling stacks, calling destructors or any of the other [RAII fun](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) you may (and should) be taking advantage of.

Comment: @user4581301 - good catch.  He should invoke `PostQuitMessage` to signal to his message pump to exit gracefully instead of calling `ExitThread` directly.

Comment: It is [not recommended](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971.aspx) to call `CreateThread()` inside of `DllMain()`.

Comment: @Remy Routine to do so when injecting

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I wish the wording was changed in the referenced document. Creating a thread is perfectly safe, and with the call to `DisableThreadLibraryCalls` you also don't have to worry about an invisible, re-entrant code path.

Comment: Bump, still cant get this to work.. can you find any more issues??

Answer (score 3):

Here's an obvious problem.

```
CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Initiate, 0, 0, 0);
```

The explicit cast of `Initiate` to LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE is the dead giveaway.

Declare Initiate as follows:

```
DWORD __stdcall Initiate(void* pData)
{
     ...
}
```

And the remove the explicit cast from CreateThread:

```
CreateThread(0, 0, Initiate, 0, 0, 0);
```

Dll injection is just going to lead to system instability no matter what your good intentions are.  It appears you don't understand thread invocation on Windows as well as a system programmer should - and that is all the more reason you shouldn't be doing DLL injection. Tread carefully.

Comment: I appreciate your concern but I'm not a programmer yet - I'm 13. I however, do hope to one day be a programmer such as yourself.

Comment: You're programming, so you're a programmer.